# 2d array sorting, white space messing the order

Tags: c++

good day, my sorting 2d array is working just fine. but, if i add white space, things got messy and out of order..

here is the normal sorting without space

```
   0  1  2  3  4  5
0| a  b  c  d  e  f
1| g  h  i  j  k  l
Press any key to continue . . .

Descending

   0  1  2  3  4  5
0| l  k  j  i  h  g
1| f  e  d  c  b  a

Ascending
   0  1  2  3  4  5
1| a  b  c  d  e  f
0| g  h  i  j  k  l
```

but if i change one of the elements into white space and becomes messy and out of order.

```
   0  1  2  3  4  5
0| a     c  d  e  f
1| g  h  i  j  k  l
Press any key to continue . . .

Descending

   0  1  2  3  4  5
0| l  k  j  i  h  g
1| f  e  d  c  a

Ascending
   0  1  2  3  4  5
1|    a  c  d  e  f
0| g  h  i  j  k  l
```

how can i ignore the white space and sort like  this?

```
   0  1  2  3  4  5
0| a     c  d  e  f
1| g  h  i  j  k  l
Press any key to continue . . .

Descending

   0  1  2  3  4  5
0| l  k  j  i  h  g
1| f  e  d  c    a

Ascending

   0  1  2  3  4  5
1| a     c  d  e  f
0| g  h  i  j  k  l
```

here is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

std::string myarray[3][6] = {{"a","b","c","d","e","f"},
                            {"g","h","i","j","k","l"},
                            {" "," "," "," "," "," "}}; //i made some allowance so that i can insert/delete


void display();

using namespace std;

int main(){

    int Rows = 2;
    int Cols = 6;

    display();
    system("pause");

    //buble sort, ascending
    cout<<"\nDescending" <<endl;
    for(int x = 0; x<2; x++){
        for(int y = 0; y<6;y++){
            for(int z = 0;z<Cols*Rows-1; z++){
                if(myarray[0][z]<myarray[0][z+1])
                swap(myarray[0][z],myarray[0][z+1]);
            }
        }
    }

  display();


  cout<<"\nAscending" <<endl;

    for(int z = 0; z<6; z++){
        cout<<"  "<<z;
    }
    cout<<endl;

    for(int x = 1; x>=0; x--){
    cout<<x <<"|";
        for(int y = 5; y>=0; y--){
            cout<<" " <<myarray[x][y] <<" "; 
        }
    cout<<endl;
    }


}

//display
void display(){

    cout<<endl;
    for(int z = 0; z<6; z++){
        cout<<"  "<<z;
    }
    cout<<endl;

    for(int x = 0; x<2; x++){
    cout<<x <<"|";
        for(int y = 0; y<6; y++){
            cout<<" " <<myarray[x][y] <<" "; 
        }
    cout<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: How should " bd" be sorted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can't.**

These results are not "messy and out of order"; the computer did exactly what you asked it to do: sort the elements. By default `' '` comes before all the letters.

By adjusting your sorting algorithm to use something other than a basic `char < char` comparison, you could make `' '` come in some other specific place in the sorting order (which would never change), but your computer can't magically guess that you meant for it to stand in for a `'b'`, or a `'l'`, or a `'z'` or whatever other character it is that day. That is the opposite of "ignoring the whitespace".

*If* the elements will always be members of the latin alphabet, and *if* there will only ever be one whitespace, and *if* there will only ever be one letter missing from the alphabet, then you could do a pre-sorting step that changes the whitespace into the missing alphabet character, then sort, then I suppose change the character back into a whitespace again afterwards. But: (a) honestly, why? (b) the sorting algorithm itself remains unchanged.

Comment: i see, sorry i didn't not notice it that it sorting just fine. i just feel dizzy coding for hours.   so is it possible to just move it or replace the white space with its next element?

Comment: reading again your answer things get clarified and made sense. thanks again

Comment: @noobiee: No problem. Perhaps get some sleep!